# Unhandled exception/Access violation reading location while trying to draw a cylinder using VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo

I'm trying to draw a cylinder using VBOs and I'm stuck with this access violation.
This is the code (formatted for the example):

```
int N;
float *vertexArray, normalArray;

void fillArrays(float height, float radius, int num) {

N = num;
vertexArray = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*36*num);
normalArray = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*36*num);
... 
}
```

The function above just fills the arrays with the normal vectors and vertices.

```
void drawCylinder() {
GLuint buffers[2];
glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 144*N, vertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 144*N, normalArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,vertexArray);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,normalArray);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*N);
}
```

The exception is thrown in the glDrawArrays call. I'm calling drawCylinder() in GLUT's display callback function (renderfunc). The main function looks like this:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) {

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
glutCreateWindow("Glew - VBOs - Cylinder");

glutDisplayFunc(renderfunc);
glutIdleFunc(renderfunc);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

fillArrays(3,1,20);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

There are probably various issues with my code, I've just started playing around with VBOs (and with the openGL libs for that matter). But is there an obvious reason for this exception to be thrown? I'm using Visual Studio, and as I said, the access violation is apparently detected when calling glDrawArrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,vertexArray);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,normalArray);
```

If you're using VBOs the `gl*Pointer()` `pointer` argument should be an offset into your buffer, not a native pointer.  Native pointers are for vertex arrays.

Also, re-uploading your vertex data before each draw call defeats the purpose of VBOs somewhat, especially with the `GL_STATIC_DRAW` hint.

[This](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) is a decent VBO example.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. That tutorial was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding genpfault's answer:

> calling drawCylinder() in GLUT's display callback function

And inside the `drawCylinder` you create/bind buffers?

So lets say if you create a keyboard interactive rotation, each time you press a key to rotate the object, a new buffer will be bound. Eventually, memory will be used up and maybe cause some stack overflow.

You can create an `init()` function throw buffer initialization code to the `init()` and call before your `glutDisplayFunc()`